# Can a friend iterator access non static data members?

Tags: c++, iterator, friend

I have a class A and a simple (and very limited) iterator A_iterator pointing to this class and being its friend:

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A_iterator{
public:
    A_iterator(int index) : _index(index) {}
    int operator*();
private:
    int _index;
};

class A{
    friend class A_iterator;
public: 
    typedef A_iterator iterator;
    A() {   _elems.push_back(1); _elems.push_back(2);   }   
private:
    static vector<int> _elems;  //line  19
};

vector<int> A::_elems; // line 22

int A_iterator::operator*()
{
    return A::_elems[_index];  //line   26  
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    A::iterator it(0);
    cout << *it << endl; //line 33
}
```

This works fine. However, I don't want _elems to be static. If I will remove static keyword from line 19 and remove line 22, how then I should modify line 26? Line 33 cannot be changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, friendship is orthogonal to `static` vs. non-static data members. You will need to change your iterator to contain a pointer/reference to the container over which it is iterating, and use that pointer/reference instead of the static member:

```
class A;
class A_iterator{
public:
    A_iterator(A &container, int index) : _index(index), _container(&container) {}
    int operator*();
private:
    int  _index;
    A   *_container;
};
//...
int A_iterator::operator*()
{
    return _container->_elems[_index];  //line   26  
}
int main() {
   A a;
   A::iterator it(a,0);
   std::cout << *it << "\n";
}
```

Comment: And then provide an iterator factory on `A`, to be consistent with STL.  (The STL containers do this everywhere, `begin()` and `end()` for example.)  It's not technically necessary, but `A`'s consumers shouldn't really have to know how iterators are constructed.

Comment: @cdhowie: yes, there are quite a few things that could be improved, and the best approach might actually be not to implement the `iterator` type at all... provide a `typedef std::vector<int>::iteartor iterator` inside `A` and implement `A::iterator A::begin() { return _elems.begin(); }` (similar for `end()`)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return (*_container)._elems[_index];` at line 26? Anyway, this is an awesome answer.